# Share picture folder with webdav

Tags: webdav

I have a folder shared on SMB containing pictures and I want the same folder to be available read only on webdav, how can I do that ?

I have found a guide and have got webdav up and running and its working with a fresh folder with correct permission, but I have problem todo the same with a existing folder....

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the problem is user permissios.....

I have had a SMB shares for years and now I have followed these guide:
https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/groups-connect-webdav-ubuntu.aspx

and it worked fin following the example by using folder: /var/www/DavLock

But when I tro to change to /mnt/privat/pictures/ I have problem to get it working...

Picture:
drwxrwx--- 208 www-data privat  12288 Nov 23 08:40  .
drwxrwx---   9 hildrum  privat   4096 Nov 24 12:55  ..

Sub folders:
drwxrwx---   2 www-data privat   4096 Nov  8  2015 'xxxxxxx'